# How to find the exactly values that caused nil exception from Crashes report in Xcode Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm investigating real user issues through Crashes report in Xcode Organizer.

[image]

Xcode tells the error line but don't give any information which value exactly caused the exception. There are many candidates to investigate.
I think it is not difficult work for Xcode to let me know which value caused the exception.

So.. I wonder is it possible to know which value exactly caused the nil exception from the crashes report?

Comment: “I think it is not difficult work for Xcode to let me know which value caused the exception.” Instead of blaming Xcode, write better code. Your exclamation points are the possible sites of these crashes. So eliminate them. There should no exclamation points in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of blaming Xcode, write better code. Your exclamation points are the possible sites of these crashes. So eliminate them. There should be no exclamation points in your code. They *mean* "please crash me", so you can hardly complain when the runtime does just what you asked it to do.

For instance, as an example, where you say `standardDate!`, instead, ask yourself: if `standardDate` is `nil`, we will crash, so what would be an acceptable substitute in that case?

- If your answer is that there is no acceptable substitute, as it should never be `nil`, then the crash is *good*, as you are being alerted to a bug elsewhere in the program. Go off and figure out what that bug is.
- If there is an acceptable substitute in that case, such as the empty string, then use it here, e.g. `standardDate ?? ""`. In this way, eliminate *all* uses of exclamation points in your app.

There are a few well-documented situations where an exclamation point is pretty much inevitable and cannot be eliminated, such as an `@IBOutlet` declaration or a cell subclass downcast, but otherwise there should be *no* exclamation marks in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The exclamation variables like `standardDate!' and 'gRoomId!' should not be nil. I tried to reproduce the nil exception but I couldn't. It seems it happens at very low probability so I questioned to know at least which variables cause it.

Comment: You could ask a new question showing how those variables get their values, and then we can talk about why they might be nil...

Answer (score 0):

I think best approach and main approach for hunting the `nil` value is :

**breakpoints** in debug mode. So you can put breakpoints your specific lines and catch the `nil` value just before.

Comment: Thank you for your replying. The problem is I can't reproduce the nil exception. It seems the probability of that happening is very low.